# Getting a node in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Simple question. I have a TreePath to a node in my JTree. How can I convert this TreePath to the DefaultMutableTreeNode the TreePath points too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to call `getLastPathComponent` on the `TreePath` and cast that for a `TreeNode` or `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and be good to go.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getLastPathComponent%28%29

Answer (score 8):

If your treemodel consists of DefaultMutableTreeNodes you may just use
`node=(DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();`

Answer (score 2):

model is a DefaultTreeModel

```
private TreePath getTreePath(TreeNode node) {
    TreeNode[] nodes = model.getPathToRoot(node);
    TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);
    return path;
}
```